# how to add a controller and action in global.aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

**here is my code as follows**

```
string sTime = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartTime"].ToString();
            string eTime = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndTime"].ToString();
            DateTime nTime = DateTime.Now;
            var startHour = Int32.Parse(sTime);
            var endHour = Int32.Parse(eTime);
            if (nTime.Hour < startHour || nTime.Hour >= endHour)
            {
                InvokeUnderMaintenance();
            }
```

**while debugging this after checking the condition its entering into the method and the method is as follows**

```
void InvokeUnderMaintenance()
        {
            //var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
            //httpContext.Response.Clear();
            //httpContext.ClearError();
            //httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "UnderMaintenance");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");

        }
```

in this method the **control is entering but not redirecting to the index page** can any one help me regarding **how to add controller and index page so that i can redirect to the page if the condition is true.**

Comment: What you need are `Action` filters: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/filters-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-0-part-twelve/

Comment: @RahulSharma no it was not helpful what i want is i have a controller and and view and i wanna add that controller and view to this method

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you wanna achieve,
this may help you

```
RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("controller", "UnderMaintenance");
routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext { RouteData = routeData };
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
return routeData;
```

Comment: i wanna redirect  to view from invokeundermaintenance method so i wanna a controller and action to that meathod

Comment: for that you need to setup current request context. Try setting up
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData

Comment: its redirecting to this page

         ` routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                //defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "IndexSideMenu", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                defaults: new { controller = "ClientEnquiry", action = "ScheduleList", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }``

Comment: If you are calling "InvokeUnderMaintenance()" inside action method, You should return path of action method and do return Redirect